# Linux shell and sort -t and -k

Tags: linux, shell, sorting

I am using a Linux shell script to create 5-fold cross validation to movielens data.  Can anyone explain to me what:

1. `sort -k 1,1n` means?  I know it means start from column `1` and ends at `1n` but what does `1n` mean?
2. My data is like `****::****::***`, that is to say, the separator is `::`, but neither "::" nor "::" work  for the `sort -t` option. Can you tell me what is the right way to set `::` as the separator? (`sort -t " "` means the separator is space; this works, but my file's separator is not space.)

```
trap `rm -f tmp.$$; exit 1` 1 2 15 # trap begin to execute the cmd in the quote when it meet signal 1,2 and 15
batch=200000
totalTuple=1000000
#$$ is the process id
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 #five fold cross validation,  train/test is one fold
do
    head -`expr $i \* ${batch}` u.data | tail -`expr ${batch}` > tmp.$$  # take the ith 1/5 block
    # expr return the cmd result as string
    sort -t"\:\:" -k 1,1n -k 2,2n tmp.$$ > u$i.test
    #sort -k -k, --key=KEYDEF sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type
    #sort -t, --field-separator=SEP
    head -`expr \( $i - 1 \) \* ${batch}` u.data > tmp.$$
    tail -`expr \( 5 - $i \) \* ${batch}` u.data >> tmp.$$
    sort -t"\:\:" -k 1,1n -k 2,2n tmp.$$ > u$i.base
done
```

Comment: `sort --help` has the answers to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The `sort -k 1,1n` means sort on field one (only) and do a numeric sort.

Sort `-t` expects a single character to separate fields.  Therefore, you'll have to do one of two things:

1. Count an empty field in between each `::` pair.
2. Munge the data so that the `::` separators are replaced by some other character.  Whether it is safe to use `:` is debatable; it depends whether your data can have `:` on its own anyway.  You could use a control character such as `FS` (field separator, <kbd>Control-\</kbd>, 0x1C, octal 034) with a fair degree of confidence that it won't appear in your normal data.

Munging (and unmunging) might be done with Bash (using [ANSI C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)) and `sed`:

```
sed -e $'s/::/\x1C/g' tmp.$$ |
sort -t $'\x1C' -k 1,1n -k 2,2n
sed -e $'s/\x1C/::/g' > u$i.base
```

Comment: but sort -k 1,1n -k 2,2n means sort on column 1 and 2,  and 1n means numerical sort on column one, 2n means numerical sort on column 2?

Comment: The `-k1,1` part means 'sort on column 1, stopping at the end of column 1 (rather than continuing to other fields); the `n` qualifier, which can also be used as `-k 1n,1` means numeric (ascending) sort.  Similarly with `-k 2,2n` — sort on field 2 (only) numerically.